# React Native FLatList render some of items

Tags: react-native

i send the data from the backen and want to show some of the items on the flatlist the flatlist render all the data i want to render the latest 3 items

**FlatList**

```
   <FlatList 
    data={props.data}
    disableVirtualization={false}
    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
    snapToInterval={90}
    decelerationRate='fast'
    renderItem={({item}) =>{
     return(
         <View style={{height: 100, width: 350}}>
         <View style={globalStyles.transactionContainer}>
          <Text style={globalText.h3}>{item.type}</Text>
          <Text style={globalText.h3}>{item.amount}</Text>
        </View>
      
      </View>
     )}}
   />
   
  </View>
```

Comment: Fetch only the last 3 from the API endpoint that is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<FlatList 
    data={props.data.slice(0, 3)}
    inverted
    disableVirtualization={false}
    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
    snapToInterval={90}
    decelerationRate='fast'
    renderItem={({item}) =>{
     return(
         <View style={{height: 100, width: 350}}>
         <View style={globalStyles.transactionContainer}>
          <Text style={globalText.h3}>{item.type}</Text>
          <Text style={globalText.h3}>{item.amount}</Text>
        </View>
      
      </View>
     )}}
   />
```

I add `inverted` prop and add a slice on you data

Comment: thanks it works , i want to render same data on other screen but with all data items can be done with same FlatList?

Comment: Yes, in that case just remove these props

Comment: but this render the 3 first items, there is an way to show the last 3 items?

Comment: just add `inverted` in props